# Bootstrap3: Dropdown items overlapping in vertical Navigation Bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Running into an issue with a vertical navbar in Bootstrap.

Check out the Code Pen here: [link](http://codepen.io/NeeksGit/pen/BojNGb?editors=110)

Note how the "works" section is showing a traditional drop down? I want that to be smoothly inline with the nav, and not pop out into a dropdown that covers the other items. I've fiddled with this thing for HOURS. I'm sure it has something to do with the position,display, or default bootstrap properties.

To clarify, I'm looking for [a UI like this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation) submenu. See how the "Works" section pushes the menu items below it down?

Have any pointers?

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="nav items">
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Works <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li>
             <a href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
             </li>
             <li>
             <a href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
      <li><span></span>Dashboards </li>
      <li><span></span>Game Finder</li>
      <li><span></span>Channel</li>
      <li><span></span>My Profile</li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="pagewrapper">
  <div id="hamburger">
      <div id='top'></div>
      <div id='middle'></div>
      <div id='bottom'></div>
    </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class "container">
      <a class="pull-right" href="#">
        <img src="" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .navbar {
  background-color: #33669a;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2.82px 0.18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  height: 58px;
  padding: 7px 40px 7px 0;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-colour: rgba 0, 0, 0, 0.2;
}

#title {
  color: #fafafa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2em;
}

#hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
}
#hamburger div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: #00DFFC;
  transition: transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91), opacity 500ms, background-color 250ms;
}

#hamburger.active {
  left: 230px;
}
#hamburger.active div {
  background-color: #343838;
  z-index: 5000;
}
#hamburger.active #top {
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-135deg);
}
#hamburger.active #middle {
  opacity: 0;
  /* transform: rotate(135deg); */
}
#hamburger.active #bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: -275px;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #343838;
  transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.28, 0.91);
  z-index: 1500;
  box-shadow: 14px 24px 37.6px 2.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.items {
  position: relative;
  top: 140px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.items li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  transition: all 250ms;
  width: 100%;
}
.items li:hover {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  background-color: rgba(52, 56, 56, 0.2);
}
.items li:hover a {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar-head {
  background-color: #33669a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 144px;
}

.sidebar-img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 23px;
  top: 24px;
}

.sidebar-img img {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.username {
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 23px;
  top: 100px;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think this issue is about `padding` of `a` tag. Just remove it it will be smooth and inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming you do not want the hash colour that is in the background of 'Works' tab. 
There is a style of bootstrap that does:

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus{
     text-decoration: none;
     background-color: #eee; 
}
```

Now overwrite the background color in your css file like,

```
 .nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus{
         text-decoration: none;
         background-color: transparent !important; 
    }
```

And if you want to remove the dancing effect then:

```
.items li:hover {
    /* padding: 15px 45px; */
}
```

Overwrite this and comment the padding in index.html.

Comment: It's not the padding. I clarified in my above edits.

Comment: From my understanding the 'League selector' in the code pen is working as per the bootsnip(drop down now pushes the options down). What is your exact expectation now?

Answer (score 0):

It is picking the property from bootstrap

```
.nav>li>a{position:relative;display:block;padding:10px 15px}
```

Add

```
  .nav>li>a{position:relative;display:block;padding:1px 1px !important}
```

to your own style.css to override bootstrap

Comment: It's not the padding. I clarified in my above edits.

Comment: Did you try my code ? I tested it on your website, it's working fine.